# How can i instantiate an object in a loop and add each instance to a list?

Tags: python, attributes

Hi I get the error message here : AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'tag'
here's my code:

```
class Move:
    def __init__(self, tag, quantity, date):
        self.tag = tag
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.date = date

moves_list = []
const_weight = 15

def last_tag():
    JSON_file = open('movements.json')
    myList = json.load(JSON_file)
    JSON_file.close()
    print(myList[-1].tag)
    return myList[-1].tag

def last_date():
    JSON_file = open('movements.json')
    myList = json.load(JSON_file)
    JSON_file.close()
    print(myList[-1].date)
    return myList[-1].date
while True:
    tag_rilevato = last_tag()
    if my_tag == last_tag():
            m = Move(my_tag, const_weight, last_date())
            moves_list.append(m)
```

I don't understand if there's something wrong with `myList[-1].tag` or `myList[-1].quantity` or `myList[-1].date`  ? and can anyone suggest something thank you very much

Comment: `json.load()` returns a `dict` object, not a `Move` object. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the return of `json.load()` as a *dictionary*, and not your `Move` object. So use `['tag']` instead of `.tag`. Like so:

```py
def last_tag():
    with open('movements.json', 'r') as fh:
        myList = json.load(fh)
    return myList[-1]['tag']

def last_date():
    with open('movements.json', 'r') as fh:
        myList = json.load(fh)
    return myList[-1]['date']

# Rest of code is unchanged
```

I also changed the file reading/writing to the recommended `with open() as..` syntax. This is not required to fix your issue, of course.

Comment: Than you Collin this helped very much, i still get errors though, i suspect when my file is empty it crashes, and i chose to modify it like this `with open('movements.json', 'r') as j:
            myList = json.loads(j.read())`  i don't know if this is wrong

Comment: The documentation suggests that the `json.load()` function takes a file object (i.e. `fh` or `j` in my/your code), and `json.loads()` takes a string. So in your case you could either do `json.load(j)` or `json.loads(j.read())` - they're functionally identical.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification Collin ! That was really helpful.